# Trend Tracking Within a Custom List

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, versioning, reports

Is it possible to track a field's changes over time in SharePoint Online within a custom list. For example a task confidence rating, which would vary over time. Within view versions there are dates and the associated changed field. Is there a way of viewing this data over multiple records? Power query within excel does not seem to be able to pull past version data through.

The ultimate goal is to be able to report on trends across multiple records within a list

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Comment: Oh, I have a Codeplex project which exports version history of SP 2013 on premise and SP 2010. It is a farm based solution though. https://exportversionhistorysp2013.codeplex.com/